# How do you read the version hash of the current PWA in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, service-worker

I'd like to be able to read the currently active hash of my Angular PWA. However I can't see any mechanism for doing that.

The SwUpdate object provides observables that allow you to read the current version's hash *when a new version is activated or when it becomes available* but doesn't seem to expose any static method for getting the hash of the current version.

```
class SwUpdate {
  available: Observable<UpdateAvailableEvent>
  activated: Observable<UpdateActivatedEvent>
  unrecoverable: Observable<UnrecoverableStateEvent>
  isEnabled: boolean
  checkForUpdate(): Promise<void>
  activateUpdate(): Promise<void>
}
```

I'd like to be able to read something like `SwUpdate.current` to read the current hash value (say `a518f9f1ab65954c2eafa02fec134fa54b391651`) without having to wait for an `available` or `activated` event. Is this possible?

Comment: it is possible to read the hash of the current update, but only if a update is avaiable. this.swUpdates.avaiable.subscribe(event => { console.log(event.current.hash); });

Comment: That's a good flag - the challenge is that I want to be able to read it so as to ask a user what version they are currently running. So I need to be able to access it whether or not an update is available.

Comment: According to this: https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops#debugging-the-angular-service-worker if you setup your service worker you `should` be able to debug it on  `yourUrl:yourPort/ngsw/state`. If that's the case you could request that page via http to get the current hash.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi - it's a good spot but that `/state` file is in fact in a virtual directory that's generated by Angular itself. However it's got to be created by angular somewhere right? So I tracked it down to here... https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/a92a89b0eb127a59d7e071502b5850e57618ec2d/packages/service-worker/worker/src/debug.ts#L40 I haven't tried it yet but I think that the `Debuggable` service may be the key to reading it - good suggestion

Comment: @PeterNixey Did you succeed on that?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I haven't yet tried it but will come back and update when I eventually do. For the time being I've been reading the timestamp that angular prints onto the manifest file and using that as my key instead. Sub-optimal but functional!

Comment: I'll look forward to see if you have had any success, I'm also willing to check using `state` if that's possible so I may come back too to this.

Comment: UPDATE: I've now tried to use `Debuggable` but it doesn't seem to be exposed in a way that you can import it anywhere. This is a bit of a crappy interim solution but I'm just going to write the value of `event.latestVersion` to local storage and then read it on next load

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SwUpdate` from `@angular/service-worker` to do that. For example, you can check that on `app.component.ts` like this:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SwUpdate } from '@angular/service-worker';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private swUpdate: SwUpdate) {}

  checkForUpdate() {
    if (this.swUpdate.isEnabled) {
      this.swUpdate.available.subscribe((event) => {
        console.log('Update is available!');
        console.log('Current version: ' + event.current.hash);
        console.log('New available version: ' + event.available.hash);
      });
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.checkForUpdate();
  }
}
```

Comment: This doens't unfortunately solve the "current version" problem. The `swUpdate.available` observable that you've registered your handler on only emits when a new version is available. So while it does let you read the current version it only does so when a new one becomes available

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that requirement when I read question. I just checked docs and didn't find anything. I would suggest you to open a GitHub issue, or email an Angular team directly.

Comment: I just clarified the question based on your answer - it wasn't quite as clear before. - TY

Comment: I gave you the bounty to avoid it evaporationg Nenad :)

Comment: Thank you! Did you find the solution?

Comment: I haven't tested it but there's some discussion in the comments under the question that suggests what it might be...

Comment: One more remark: if the PWA is deleted the current hash is not empty, because the current and available fields are containing the service worker versions